# Daily average calculation from multiple year daily weather data?

Tags: r, average

I have a daily data for 31 years from 1984 to 2014. I would like to compute the daily average for 31 years for the variables

```
date    Min_daily   Max_daily   Rain_daily 
01-01-1984  18.8    3.6          0  
02-01-1984  20.2    3.8          0  
03-01-1984  19      4.2          0
.
.
.
30-12-2014  19.4    2.2          0
31-12-2014  18.5    7            0
01-01-2015  17.2    7.2          0
```

How to do it in R software?

Comment: What do you mean by daily average? You can't compute an average of a group of values using only the min and max values. For example, `mean(c(1, 2, 300))` and `mean(c(1,200, 300))` are not equal.

Comment: @RobJensen the OP wants to average each day over 31 years for 366 different averaged mins, maxes, and rains.

Comment: Dataset is having 31 (years) *365.25 (days per year) ~11,323 rows and I want to have the average of 31 years daily values which will give 365 rows only.

Comment: @BappaDas it will give 366 days.

Comment: Please use `dput(my_data_frame)` (or even just a subset of your data), then include the output in your question.  That way, others are more likely to give you the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new variable

```
yourData$day <- format(yourData$date, format='%m-%d')
```

And use your favorite mean aggregator, in base R `tapply` or `aggregate` work a treat.

Example: `aggregate(cbind(Min_daily, Max_daily, Rain_daily) ~ day, data=yourData)`

Comment: format(yourData$date, format='%m-%d') is returning the day in "1984-01-01" "1984-01-02" "1984-01-03" "1984-01-04" "1984-01-05" format. I am not getting the desired results. I am using the following codes: data$day <- format(data$date, format='%m-%d')
aggregate(cbind(Min_daily, Max_daily, Rain_daily) ~ day, data=data,FUN=mean)

Comment: @BappaDas is "date" in fact a date? If not, make it so or just use `substr`.

Comment: can you please elaborate the code please so that I get the desired results

Comment: Use `as.Date(data$date, format='%d-%m-%Y')` to transform the vector into a date. Or use `substr(data$date, 1, 5)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @AdamO, the as.Date(data$date, format='%d-%m-%Y') has done the trick for me.